# When can I use "peoples" in a sentence and have it be grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality

I need help for this story I'm writing. I have been told before that you can't use the word "peoples" in a sentence because it is not grammatically correct or doesn't exist by many people.

If I were to say *... capacity of 150 peoples.* would it be grammatically correct? If not, when can I use "peoples"?

Comment: Yeah, you'd usually see "capacity of 150 persons".  (Or, even more often, "capacity 150", leaving you to guess whether that's people, cats, or earwigs.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Peoples* is the plural of *people* when *people* means *a nation or ethnic group,* or the like.  For example, there is a book called *Africa, its peoples and their cultural history.*  This title does not indicate a history of individual Africans, but of African tribes and nations.

*People* is the usual plural of *person,* meaning *individual human,* although one also sees *persons.*  When speaking about a number of individuals, *peoples* is never correct.

In the phrase "capacity of 150 X" it is clear that you are referring to 150 individuals, so *peoples* is incorrect.  The phrase should be

> ... capacity of 150 people.

However, "persons" is more likely to appear in legislative and regulatory texts, so it would not be unusual to see an official notice restricting a room's occupancy to

> ... no more than 150 persons.

Comment: In legislative language, I think an interesting research question would be whether *persons* was **primarily** used when non-natural persons ("corporations are people too, my friend!") were included. Probably it's not that cut-and-dried, though.

Answer (score 2):

Use "peoples" when you're talking about more than one group of people.  For instance, James Forsyth wrote a book called *A History of the Peoples of Siberia: Russia's North Asian Colony 1581-1990*.  This is an ethnographic history of the region, talking about different ethnic groups.